# Reshaping Numpy Array To a Smaller Size

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset contains point clouds and images. To traing these data, I want to concatenate these arrays using numpy concatenate. But the problem is point cloud data is in shape of (20000, 3) and image is in shape of (370, 1224, 3). And while trying to concatenate,it gives me an error saying "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 589614 into shape (370,1224,3)" How can I solve this? Is there another method to train this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cloud data is shaped like a long piece of string while your image is shaped like a piece of paper. Can you imagine these shapes in your head? How would you combine them?

Maybe what you want instead is a way to provide two different types of input to a model? How to do this would depend on what kind of tools you are using. Maybe this will help: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/